# pandas DataFrame from two numpy row vectors

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Hi I am a bit stuck creating a DataFrame from two column vectors:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'col1':np.arrange(0,11,1)}, {'col2':np.arrange(0,11,1)} )
```

I always get the error "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (11, 1), indices imply (1, 1)"
But if I create them both individually it works WHY?

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'col1':np.arrange(0,11,1)})
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame( {'col1':np.arrange(0,11,1), 'col2':np.arrange(0,11,1)} )`

Comment: you have 2 separate `dictionaries` being passed to the `df`  -  thats the problem

Comment: thanks :) that was the issue